# Is It possible to add permissions to specific url in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using IsAuthenticated permission by default and let's say I do not want to change the default permission. Is it possible to give permission of AllowAny to a specific URL?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/section/', include('section.urls')),
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Great Soft Uz')) # I want this url to be public
]
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include_docs_urls function has a parameter with a default value like this 
permission_classes=api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES

```py
def include_docs_urls(
        title=None, description=None, schema_url=None, urlconf=None,
        public=True, patterns=None, generator_class=SchemaGenerator,
        authentication_classes=api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,
        permission_classes=api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES,
        renderer_classes=None):
# this is the declaration of the function
```

the default behavior is to extend the value of  DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES from you settings but you can override it like this

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Great Soft Uz', permission_classes=[AllowAny, ], authentication_classes=[])) 
]
```

Comment: ```from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls``` from where I got include_docs_url

Comment: I can change it going to the ```import_docs_urls``` as well but is in the library and I think that is not the proper way

Comment: can you clarify what really you want , so I can help you . The best way to make permissions related to a View class as I have mentioned in my answer , this is what I understood from you question . I waiting for more clarification from you .

Comment: I want one specific url to be public - and it is a built-in library function, My default permission is IsAuthenticated. I do not want to change it.

Comment: I edited my answer , try it and tell me what you get I am waiting

Comment: Thank you very much, You can't imagine how helpful it was. Thanks again))

Comment: You are welcome , and sorry for misunderstanding at first. have a nice day